# Bash Auto-completion with Tab button doesn't complete at some condition

Tags: linux, bash, autocomplete

We know some commands doesn't work on some files/directories. As an example we cannot use "cd" command on a file and when we try to press tab button to complete our line, the system doesn't show us any file for completion.

But I encountered an interesting scenario when I try autocomplete feature to complete a file name that finish with ".a". I can explain this scenario like below:

```
[root@myserver multipath]# ls -1
idlist
idlist.a
idlist.b
multipath.a
multipath.sh
```

I have these files in a directory.

- When I type "vim m" and then press the "tab" button the system auto-complete this command as "vim multipath.sh".
- When I type "vim idlist" and then press the "tab" button the system show me two option: "idlist" and "idlist.b". There is no "idlist.a" option.
- And finally, when I use "cat (or anything else)" the system show me files that finish with ".a" (with all options). There is no confusing something at there.

What is the secret behind of ".a"? Why the system does not complete this files when we use vi/vim command?

Comment: Can you please show output of **`complete-filename idlist[TAB]`** ? Just to see If bash recognizes that file ending with `.a` or not.

Comment: sorry i don't get it. what command do I use? is "complete-filename" a command? but if you accept "cat" command or something like that, the output is: 
cat idlist[tab]
-- idlist idlist.a idlist.b --
.
if I use vim:
vim idlist[tab]
-- idlist idlist.b --

Comment: Just write **`complete-filename idlist[TAB]`**. Press `TAB` **not** Enter. Also what is your $SHELL ?

Comment: i cannot use complete-filename command, i have not that. there is a command named "complete". But still if i try to do this, the output is same with output of "cat" (idlist idlist.a idlist.b). The problem is only with vi/vim as I see. and the shell: echo $SHELL --> /bin/bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my Kubuntu there is no `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/vim` file, but the file

```
/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
```

contains this line:

> ```
> _install_xspec '*.@(o|so|so.!(conf|*/*)|a|[rs]pm|gif|jp?(e)g|mp3|mp?(e)g|avi|asf|ogg|class)' vi vim gvim rvim view rview rgvim rgview gview emacs xemacs sxemacs kate kwrite
> ```

Note there are lines for different tools, lots of them.

If I enable `set -x` and then `vim`<kbd>tab</kbd>, I see the pattern being used multiple times, finally even with an uppercase version of it, like this:

> ```
> compgen -f -X '!!(*.@(o|so|so.!(conf|*/*)|a|[rs]pm|gif|jp?(e)g|mp3|mp?(e)g|avi|asf|ogg|class)|*.@(O|SO|SO.!(CONF|*/*)|A|[RS]PM|GIF|JP?(E)G|MP3|MP?(E)G|AVI|ASF|OGG|CLASS))' --
> ```

I temporarily removed `|a` from the `bash_completion` file. New instances of `bash` began to recognize `*.a` (and `*.A`) files.

I believe the pattern specifies files one wouldn't usually want to edit as text. [This list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_filename_extensions_(A%E2%80%93E)#A) (which is obviously case-insensitive) tells us `a` may denote a library in Unix. My guess is this is the reason to exclude it. Note `o` and `so` are other common extensions for binary files in Unix, they are also in the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had inadvertently turned off posix option.

```
set +o posix
```

restored the tab filename completion functionality.